# Break a while loop when a button is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpiozero

I am currently trying to setup this code so that when a button in this case `button1` connected to a RPi GPIO runs the function `c1` and keeps looping that function until another button `button2` is pressed and then it runs the function `c2` keep looping in that function.

```
    #Import RPi GPIO module
    from gpiozero import Button

    #Assign name to buttons GPIO pins
    button1 = Button(2)
    button2 = Button(4)

    def c1():
        while True:
            print('c1')
            grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
            if grade < 10:
            print('Less than 10')
        else:
            print ('invalid input')

   def c2():
       while True:
            print('c2')
            grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
            if grade < 10:
                print('Less than 10')
            else:
                print ('invalid input')
```

I encountered troubles breaking the function `c1`, I have tried to add a `break` in the `while` when another button is pressed as follows without any luck as the code doesn't stop.

```
    def c1():
        while True:
            print('c1')
            grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
        if grade < 10:
            print('Less than 10')
        elif button2.is_pressed:
            break
```

I have also tried this to break the loop but I'm not even sure it is a correct way to do it, anyhow it did not work.

```
    def c1():
        while True:
            print('c1')
            grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
            if grade < 10:
                print('Less than 10')
            elif button2.is_pressed:
                c1() == False
                break
```

I am not sure to be correct but I have a feeling that something has to change the function let's assume `c1` to `False` to break the loop. I was hoping that by telling the code once a new button is pressed stop the loop would work but it didn't work out.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the **exact** code, then you may notice that the `break` is outside the `while` loop.

```
def c1():
    while True:
        print('c1')
        grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
    if grade < 10:
        print('Less than 10')
    elif button2.is_pressed:
        break
```

Meanwhile, in this code, you need to set the `boolean` variable before the `while` loop, then set it to false. You don't need the `break` if you are using this method because the function will break the `while` loop once the variable is set to false.

```
def c1():
    while True:
        print('c1')
        grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
        if grade < 10:
            print('Less than 10')
        elif button2.is_pressed:
            c1() == False
            break
```

Try this:

```
def c1():
    flag = True
    while flag == True:
        print('c1')
        grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
        if grade < 10:
            print('Less than 10')
        elif button2.is_pressed: #try using if here instead of elif
            flag = False
```

Or this:

```
def c1():
    while True:
        print('c1')
        grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
        if grade < 10:
            print('Less than 10')
        elif button2.is_pressed: #try using if here instead of elif
            break
```

EDIT: Perhaps you've missed the `elif`, try using `if` instead if that doesn't work.

EDIT 2: Further problem.

```
def c1():
    while True:
        print('c1')
        if button2.is_pressed:
            break
        grade = float(input('Select grade: '))
        if grade < 10:
            print('Less than 10')
```

Comment: The last code you posted did the job! I had though as suggested by you to change the `elif` to `if`. Now I would like to ask why do I need two `if` statements?

Comment: The `elif` statement works only when the `if` statement met the condition first.  It won't work if the `if` statement is not even executed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! I have encountered another issue. The code breaks only if I hold the button while inputting the value during the `input` prompt. Is there any way to make the code break even if it's waiting for an input?

Comment: Does that mean the button is the priority?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question 100% but yes when another button is pressed the code needs to stop regardless of anything and jump to the next code. Do you reckon is possible?

Comment: Yes, I do. You may need to reconstruct the conditions. I've edited (EDIT 2) my answer above for the solution that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you debugged your program? Have you checked that `break` was called?

It might help you find the problem.

You can also print: `button2.is_pressed` to find out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had done some debugging but not what you have suggested, how could I print the `break` to see if it is called? It might be useful for the next time

Comment: You can use a debugger (such as [`pycharm`'s debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/promo/?source=google&medium=cpc&campaign=14124132918&gclid=CjwKCAiAn5uOBhADEiwA_pZwcL3InTlCwLIwLb3fumdLvNytz5IBIsTrqCG6x8mksRdl2sgPXpnOzhoCczMQAvD_BwE) or [vscode's debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)), or just print out a message before your `break` line